# Syntax Error Converting DateTime From Character String

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to insert a row in ms-sql table using the following code

```
SqlCMDText = "INSERT INTO attendance(date, time_in, time_out, time_total, status,";
SqlCMDText += "  is_late_in, is_half_day, is_early_out, user_id, remarks)";
SqlCMDText += " VALUES('@yestarday_date', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'ABSENT', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 52, 'DONE BY PORTAL')";
SqlCMD = new SqlCommand(SqlCMDText, SqlCON);
SqlCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yestarday_date", Yestarday);
SqlCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Where Yestarday is a string variable containing short date format like "04/04/2011". I also tried passing datetime variable itself but it does not work, I get same error as below.

> "Syntax Error Converting DateTime From Character String"

What format should I use to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: your column is a datetime? so adding a parameter as a datetime should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Parse(Yestarday)`

```
SqlCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yestarday_date", DateTime.Parse(Yestarday));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ranhiru this worked. DateTime.Parse(Yestarday). But I still don't understand why direct DateTime object is not working it should work I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `DateTime` object directly. If you get another error, post that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
CurDate = DateTime.ParseExact(@Yestarday, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```